# Ionic can't run my app from the device browser

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an Android app using ionic. When I execute `ionic serve` I can see my app on my computer through `http://localhost:8100`

I checked my ip address using ipconfig and it's `192.168.0.3`, so I tried using this IP from my device (`http://192.168.0.3:8100`), but I got a 404. I then tried from the very same computer I am developing from, and I got a 404 too!

Funny thing is, ionic uses two servers:

[image]

If I put `http://192.168.0.3:35729` I can see live reload server both from my computer and my device. I didn't have to touch anything on my router to forward ports, and both my computer and my phone are on the same network. Note that I cannot access `http://192.168.0.3:8100` neither from my phone nor from my computer (the same one I am using to develop)

Also I am serving a REST web service on 8080 from a J2EE app, and I can see it in my device. My app consumes this service, and from the computer, everything works fine. But from the device, although I can use the phone browser to access the REST server, my ionic app gives me another 404 error!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a networking question, nothing to do with ionic or angular or android.

Comment: To my knowledge, it is to be something with Ionic's configuration, @MirkoN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the address Ionic has configured. Run:

```
ionic address
```

Then it will provide you a list of available addresses:

```
Multiple addresses available.
Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:
1) 192.168.0.107 (eth1)
2) localhost
```

Select your local IP from the available options. This must solve the issue you're facing.